# Is there a "not equal" in a linq join?

Tags: c#, linq, equality

I am trying accomplish the LINQ query below but I need a "not equal" instead of equal, I want to add a list of clubs that members have not joined, instead of IDClub equals i.ID, I want IDClub "not equals" i.ID

```
int IdTvien = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
List<Member> memBer= db.memBer.ToList();
          List<Club> Club = db.Club.ToList();
          List<Member_Club> member_club= db.Member_Club.ToList();
          var memBRecord= from e in member_club
                               join d in memBer on e.IDmemBer equals IdTvien into table1
                               from d in table1.ToList()
                               join i in clb on e.IDClub equals i.ID into table2
                               from i in table2.ToList()
                               select new ViewModel
                               {
                                   Member_Club = e,
                                   Member= d,
                                   Club= i
                               };
```

Comment: Don't use a join, just filter 2 result sets then combine them. Can you give us an example of what the data looks like and what you expect the result to be? The code is hard on the eyes.

Comment: You're effectively saying you want a list of clubs with no members?

Answer (score 0):

```
UserClubs_ clubs = (from a in this.db.Users
                                  join b in this.db.UserClub on a.UserNumber equals b.UserNumber into u_club
                                    where a.UserNumber == 852
                                  select new UserClubs_
                                  {
                                      assigned_clubs = (from r in this.db.ClubList
                                                        where u_club.Select(x => x.ClubId).Contains(r.Id)
                                                        select r).ToList(),
                                      user = a,
                                      not_assigned = (from r in this.db.ClubList
                                                      where !u_club.Select(x => x.ClubId).Contains(r.Id)
                                                      select r).ToList()
                                  }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Not so good but you can use something like this

some class:

```
public class UserClubs_
{
    public Users user { get; set; }
    public List<ClubList> assigned_clubs { get; set; }
    public List<ClubList> not_assigned { get; set; }
}
```

tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserClub] (
[Id]         INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[UserNumber] INT NOT NULL,
[ClubId]     INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

);

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClubList] (
[Id]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

);